# Discord.JS Random Image Search

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to code a bot in `discord.js` that generates random images. So far, I did this with cursed images, but when I copy and paste the code and change the case for 'mcimage' and the url to + "minecraft image", mcimage does work. However, cursedimage also brings up a minecraft image. How do I make it so that cursedimage brings up only cursed images and mcimage brings up only minecraft? This is my code:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');

 switch (args[0]) {
  case 'cursedimage':
   image(message);

   break;
 }
});

function image(message) {
 var options = {
  url: 'http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=' + 'cursed image',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
   Accept: 'text/html',
   'User-Agent': 'Chrome',
  },
 };

 request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
  if (error) {
   return;
  }

  $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

  var links = $('.image a.link');

  var urls = new Array(links.length)
   .fill(0)
   .map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr('href'));

  console.log(urls);

  if (!urls.length) {
   return;
  }

  message.channel.send(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass a variable with the search term for both commands like so:

```js
switch (args[0]) {
  case "cursedimage":
    image(message, "cursed image");
    break;
  case "mcimage":
    image(message, "minecraft image");
    break;
}
```

And then on your image function you can pass the search term to the url in options

```js
function image(message, searchTerm) {
  var options = {
    url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + searchTerm,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "text/html",
      "User-Agent": "Chrome",
    },
  };

  // ...

}
```